# single sign on using coldfusion with IIS version 5 using NTLM

Tags: coldfusion, single-sign-on, ntlm, iis-5, coldfusion-9

Hi can anybody direct me on this and how does this get setup.  I basically have an application that I want users to be automatically logged into when logging in windows using there id and password so basically they get authenticated to using my coldfusion application ?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I looked a little bit on web, there are partial solutions but found nothing which would match your question. Next thing would be to look what Java world has to offer there. If you find some Java library, you could use javaLoader and run it from CF. Please let us know if you managed to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

see: `<cfNTauthenticate>` tag

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c23.html

Comment: Thanks for that Henry will see what I can do with that tag :-).  Sure Zarko shall let you know once this has been resolved.

Thanks

Comment: sorry Henry would you know why my security rules are still not working as I put the rules in the secure list and it still does not work.  I have the code that i have put available under the question that i posted.

Comment: huh? I don't see any code in your question.  I haven't used NTLM myself before, so you should post your code up and maybe other experts can help you.

Comment: sorry Henry I meant for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751229/coldbox-security-interceptor

I posted the code there.